# Running SQL query on tables having name with @ or # character shows problem on different CCSID

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have a legacy database on Db2 i (Db2400), in which table (physical file) names and their fields contains some variant characters like @ and #. My application is using simple JDBC to access data in these tables.

This works fine when my IBM i machine is on default CCSID i.e. on 65535 and on English CCSID.

But SQL queries fails on CCSID like 871 (Iceland), which treats @ character differently. It gives error:

```
[SQL0113] Name T@BNAME not allowed.
```

I tried few approaches to solve the problem like setting JDBC connection url property:

"package ccsid" to 1208 (UTF-8).

"package ccsid"- Specifies the character encoding to use for the SQL package and any statements sent to the system.

Other approach was to create aliases for such tables. But if these characters are present in the column name, then we can not create alias for those without recreating table structure.

I am expecting my JDBC queries to run properly in different CCSIDs. It is recommended to not use such characters in SQL object name. But as I said my database is legacy database and can not be changed/modified easily.

Answer (score 3):

Create views instead of aliases for tables with problem characters in column names.  You can assign new names for columns in view definition.

Comment: Thanks @Satya, It seems better solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the character in CCSID 871 that matches the position of `@` in CCSID 37.

In CCSID 37 the character `@` is `x'7c'`. In CCSID 871 `x'7c'` is `Ð`. So try column name TÐBNAME.

Here are some links to the two EBCDIC tables:

- [CCSID 37](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_037)
- [CCSID 871](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC_871)

Notice that the two characters switch positions in the tables.

Comment: Yes, This is one of the way. But if we want the application run on multiple CCSIDs, we need to provide appropriate conversion for each of them.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only way to do that is to use exclusively invariant characters in field names.